# How do I start multiple screens with custom commands for each one?

Tags: linux, bash, macos, terminal, gnu-screen

I want to start multiple screens using the mac/linux command screen and have each screen execute my .bashrc and then run a series of aliases/functions from that .bashrc. I have tried adding various commands in my .screenrc as shown below:

```
screen -t first bash
screen -t SE bash
screen -t myserver bash -i --rcfile <(echo "export PS1='> ' && ls") -i
screen -t myserver bash -i
screen -t myserver /Users/user/bin/mybash
screen -t myserver mybash
screen -t myserver ~/bin/mybash
screen -t myserver bash --init-file <(echo "source .bashrc; runapp")
screen -t myserver2 bash --init-file <(echo ". .bashrc; runapp")
```

but the aliases don't get executed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are they "not working as expected"? Why are you trying to use aliases/functions for this instead of external scripts?

Comment: put all that in your ~/.screenrc, then just invoke screen with no args.

Comment: @EtanReisner, How do I make a screen call an external script when it starts?

Comment: @glennjackman, All of these are from my .screenrc. I updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here is how you can use aliases with screen.

```
~$ cat .profile 
shopt -s expand_aliases
alias ping1="ping 8.8.8.8"
alias ping2="ping 8.8.4.4"

~$ cat .screenrc 
screen -t app1 bash -lc ping1
screen -t app2 bash -lc ping2

~$ screen
```

Even though, it's possible to achieve it doesn't feel like a great idea. People are avoiding "expand_aliases" for reason.

Comment: This doesn't work if I put it in the .screenrc. Do you know the line I need to put in .screenrc?

Comment: The only reason i can see why it might not work for you is the situation when screen terminates right after command finishes. This would be the case for most of your examples - you just don't see output - only 'screen terminated' message. Some endless command like ping should do the trick.

Comment: you are absolutely right. The command is executed but the screen exits right after executing those commands.